# AndEngine - Moving Rectangle using Accelerometer

Tags: android, physics, andengine, xml

I'm learning how to create games with this great engine and I'm trying to put my knowledge in order to create a simple game. My first goal is to make a Rectangle moving using accelerometer and create levels using xml parser.

Only the second step works. In fact my player rectangle remains stuck on the screen. I noticed that if I put all my code in a BaseActivity class all works fine, but obviously I would to create few classes to make my game organized and to follow object orientation paradigm. Here is my classes and my first "try" level xml layout.

GameActivity:

```
public class GameActivity extends BaseGameActivity implements IAccelerationListener {

private Camera camera;
private ResourcesManager resourceManager;
static PhysicsWorld mPhysicsWorld;

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera = new Camera(0, 0, 800, 480);
    EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(800, 480), camera);
    mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false);

    engineOptions.setWakeLockOptions(WakeLockOptions.SCREEN_ON);

    return engineOptions;
}

@Override
public void onCreateResources(OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback) throws Exception {
    ResourcesManager.prepareManager(mEngine, this, camera, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    resourceManager = ResourcesManager.getInstance();
    pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();
}

@Override
public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
        throws Exception {
    SceneManager.getInstance().createGameScene(pOnCreateSceneCallback);

}

@Override
public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,
        OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine(EngineOptions pEngineOptions){
    return new LimitedFPSEngine(pEngineOptions, 60);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();

    if (this.isGameLoaded())
        System.exit(0);
}

@Override
public void onAccelerationAccuracyChanged(AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onAccelerationChanged(AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {
    final Vector2 gravity = Vector2Pool.obtain(pAccelerationData.getX()*3, pAccelerationData.getY()*3);
    this.mPhysicsWorld.setGravity(gravity);
    Vector2Pool.recycle(gravity);       
}

@Override
public void onResumeGame() {
        super.onResumeGame();
        this.enableAccelerationSensor(this);
}

@Override
public void onPauseGame() {
        super.onPauseGame();
        this.disableAccelerationSensor();
}

}
```

ResourceManager:

```
public class ResourcesManager {

public static final ResourcesManager INSTANCE = new ResourcesManager();

public Engine engine;
public GameActivity activity;
public Camera camera;
public VertexBufferObjectManager vbom;

public void loadMenuResources(){
    loadMenuGraphics();
}

private void loadMenuGraphics() {

}

public void loadGameResources(){
    loadGameGraphics();
    loadGameFonts();
}

private void loadGameFonts() {

}

private void loadGameGraphics() {

}

public static void prepareManager(Engine engine, GameActivity activity, Camera camera, VertexBufferObjectManager vbom){
    getInstance().engine = engine;
    getInstance().activity = activity;
    getInstance().camera = camera;
    getInstance().vbom = vbom;
}

public static ResourcesManager getInstance(){
    return INSTANCE;
}

}
```

SceneManager:

```
package com.indies.fatescape;

import org.andengine.engine.Engine;
import org.andengine.ui.IGameInterface.OnCreateSceneCallback;

public class SceneManager {

private BaseScene gameScene;
private static SceneManager INSTANCE = new SceneManager();
private SceneType currentSceneType = SceneType.SCENE_GAME;
private BaseScene currentScene;
private Engine engine = ResourcesManager.getInstance().engine;

public enum SceneType {
    SCENE_GAME,
}

public void setScene(BaseScene scene){
    engine.setScene(scene);
    currentScene = scene;
    currentSceneType = scene.getSceneType();
}

public void createGameScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback){
    gameScene = new GameScene();
    gameScene.registerUpdateHandler(GameActivity.mPhysicsWorld);
    currentScene = gameScene;
    pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(gameScene);
}

/* 
 * setScene(SceneType sceneType) which takes care about displaying another scene and keeping track of it
 * by storing references of the displayed scene and its type
 */

public void setScene(SceneType sceneType){
    switch (sceneType){
    case SCENE_GAME:
        setScene(gameScene);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

public static SceneManager getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
}

public SceneType getCurrentSceneType() {
    return currentSceneType;
}

public BaseScene getCurrentScene() {
    return currentScene;
}
```

}

GameScene:

```
public class GameScene extends BaseScene {

private PhysicsWorld physicsWorld;

private static final String TAG_LEVEL = "level";
private static final String TAG_ENTITY = "entity";
private static final String TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE = "type";
private static final String TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_X = "x";
private static final String TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_Y = "y";
private static final String TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_WIDTH = "width";
private static final String TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_HEIGHT = "height";

private static final Object TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_VALUE_BRICK = "brick";
private static final Object TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_VALUE_PLAYER = "player";

private Body playerBody;
private Rectangle player;

@Override
public void createScene() {
    createPhysics();
    createBackground();
    loadLevel(1);
}

@Override
public void onBackLeyPressed() {

}

@Override
public SceneType getSceneType() {
    return SceneType.SCENE_GAME;
}

@Override
public void disposeScene() {

}

private void createBackground() {
    setBackground(new Background(Color.BLUE));
}

private void createPhysics(){
    physicsWorld = GameActivity.mPhysicsWorld;
}

private void loadLevel(int id){
    final LevelLoader levelLoader = new LevelLoader();
    final FixtureDef FIXTURE_DEF = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0.01f, 0.5f);

    levelLoader.registerEntityLoader(TAG_LEVEL, new IEntityLoader() {

        @Override
        public IEntity onLoadEntity(String pEntityName, Attributes pAttributes) {

            return GameScene.this;
        }
    });

    levelLoader.registerEntityLoader(TAG_ENTITY, new IEntityLoader() {

        @Override
        public IEntity onLoadEntity(String pEntityName, Attributes pAttributes) {

            final Rectangle levelObject;
            final int x = SAXUtils.getIntAttributeOrThrow(pAttributes, TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_X);
            final int y = SAXUtils.getIntAttributeOrThrow(pAttributes, TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_Y);
            final int width = SAXUtils.getIntAttributeOrThrow(pAttributes, TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_WIDTH);
            final int height = SAXUtils.getIntAttributeOrThrow(pAttributes, TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_HEIGHT);
            final String type = SAXUtils.getAttributeOrThrow(pAttributes, TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE);

            if(type.equals(TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_VALUE_BRICK)){
                levelObject = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height, vbom);
                Body body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, levelObject, BodyType.StaticBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
                physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(levelObject, body, true, false));

                return levelObject;
            } else if(type.equals(TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_VALUE_PLAYER)){
                player = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height, vbom);
                playerBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, player, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
                physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(player, playerBody, true, true));

                return player;
            } else
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    });

    try {
        levelLoader.loadLevelFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "level/" + id + ".lvl");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

BaseScene:

```
public abstract class BaseScene extends Scene {

protected ResourcesManager resourcesManager;
protected Engine engine;
Activity activity;
protected Camera camera;
protected VertexBufferObjectManager vbom;

public BaseScene(){
    resourcesManager = ResourcesManager.getInstance();
    engine = resourcesManager.engine;
    activity = resourcesManager.activity;
    camera = resourcesManager.camera;
    vbom = resourcesManager.vbom;

    createScene();
}

// Abstraction

public abstract void createScene();
public abstract void onBackLeyPressed();
public abstract SceneType getSceneType();
public abstract void disposeScene();

}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level width="1000" height="780">
        <entity x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" type="player"/>
    <entity x="100" y="100" width="100" height="30" type="brick"/>
    <entity x="200" y="200" width="50" height="30" type="brick"/>
</level>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application is waiting for the signal that the `onPopulateScene` step has finished. You never send the signal, so it never starts. Change your `GameActivity` class like this:

```
@Override
public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,
        OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
    pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished(); 
}
```

This should do the trick!